# ajax fileupload not working in ie

Tags: asp.net

Able to upload files using modern browsers like Internet Explorer versions 9,10, Chrome, Firefox. But no response when used outdated browsers like **Internet Explorer versions ** 6,7,8.

HTML Source:

```
<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="ajaxFUP" runat="server" Width="200px" ThrobberID="myThrobber" ContextKeys="fred"
                    AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,pdf" MaximumNumberOfFiles="10" onuploadcomplete="ajaxFUP_UploadComplete" />
```

Code behind:

```
   protected void ajaxFUP_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/Error/") + e.FileName;
            ajaxFUP.SaveAs(path);
    }
```

Kindly provide resolution!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1024x768 and one more 1600x1200! You're welcome!

Comment: That's not a HTML source... :(

Comment: Hello sinni800.. i think the point is to get some fix for this issue! HTML source in the sense, its understood that it is aspx file we are discussing about!  So better try to give some resolution instead of pointing out! :)

Answer (score -1):

ajaxfileuplad in IE only receives the response which is declared as text/html or text/plain. So send a HTTP header to declare the response as text/html maybe effective.

ajaxfileupload processes the reponse in the following steps:

1)target the response to a iframe ( In IE, only the content declared as text/html or text/plain could be targeted to a iframe)
2)call the response callback function defined in the ajaxfileupload, which converts the content in the iframe to the content-type specified in your settings for ajaxfileupload
3)call your response callback function in your settings for ajaxfileupload

Comment: Hi Ramesh.. thnks for the reply.. i'd really appreciate if u can send me the  code!!